# Need Help to get value of selected item from Select Dropdown list in cfquery under insert query

Tags: coldfusion-9

### Form:

```
<!-- Sign up FORM -->
<cfoutput>
  <form  method="post" action="HomeShow_submit.cfm">
    <input type="hidden" name="UserID" value="#RemoveChars(CGI.Auth_User, 1, Find('\', CGI.Auth_User))#">
  <input type="hidden" name="Fname" value="#User.fname#">
  <input type="hidden" name="Lname" value="#User.lname#">
  <input type="hidden" name="Year" value="#DatePart('yyyy', Now())#">

    <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
  <th colspan="2" scope="col" class="Header" align="center">Home Show Sign Up Form</th>
        </tr>

  <tr>
  <th align="left" class="red">Shifts</th>
    <td><select name="ShiftsList">
          <option value="" selected>  ... select a Shift</option>
      <cfloop query="ShiftsList">
        <option value="#ShiftsList.ShiftDetails#">#ShiftsList.ShiftDetails#</option>
      </cfloop>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr> 

  <tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" NAME="SubmitForm"  value="Submit"></td>
  </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</cfoutput>
```

### ActionPage

```
<cfquerydatasource="HomeShow"  name="InsertHomeShow">
 INSERT INTO HomeShow
                (UserID,
        Fname,
        Lname,
        Year,
        ShiftID
        )
  VALUES
  ('#Form.USERID#',
  '#Form.Fname#',
  '#Form.Lname#',
  '#Form.Year#'
  ?              

)
</cfquery>
```

Question: This is where I need help, suppose we choose option with value =1 i.e. Friday March 20th 10.00 a.m to noon. I want to get value i.e 1 in Insert statement. So What I can write in side Insert statement to get that value.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Some suggestion helped me a lot finding the answer!!!

```
<!--Form -->
    <tr>
    <th align="left" class="red">Shifts</th>
    <td><select name="ShiftsID">            <cfloop query="ShiftsList">
<optio value="#ShiftsList.ShiftID#">#ShiftsList.ShiftDetails#</option>
                        </cfloop>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>   

<!-- Actionpage-->
<cfquery datasource="HomeShow"  name="InsertHomeShow">
    INSERT INTO HomeShow
        (UserID,
        Fname,
        Lname,
        Year,
        ShiftID
        )
        VALUES
        ('#Form.USERID#',
         '#Form.Fname#',
         '#Form.Lname#',
         '#Form.Year#',
         '#Form.ShiftsID#'
        )
```